# Не работает dll на других ПК

Tags: c++, dll

Написал dll на с++, она по API должна встраиваться в другую программу. У меня на компе, конечно же, всё прекрасно функционирует, но на других ПК программа (в которую должна быть встроена dll) пишет, что не может установить связь с моей dll. Конкретных ошибок нет.
Сборка - релиз. Компилятор - msvs. Библиотека времени исполнения(CRT) - /MT.

Пробовал просматривать зависимости с помощью dependency walker'a и подобных, он показал зависимости, я подкинул их к dll - результат не изменился, всё так же не запускает.

Comment: В какую программу встраиваете?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ServioPump, это ПО для АЗС

Comment: Хмм, а версии программы одинаковые у вас и на втором ПК? Еще вариант - C++ redist нужно поставить. Или эти dll-ки тоже с собой таскаются?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да версии полностью одинаковые. dll таскаю с собой, redist сейчас попробую

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  redist, увы, не помог

Comment: Есть еще такой вариант - сделать свою тестовую программу, которая открывала бы DLL, и выдавала более подробную ошибку, если что-то не так. И попробовать ее на целевом компьютере. Больше идей нет...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась с помощью монитора процессов. Оказывается собрал не все зависимости.
Если кому-то пригодится - то на целевом ПК открывайте ДЛЛ с помощью LoadLibrary и монитором смотрите, какие длл вызываются и насколько успешно.